# Delphi, Debug initialization section

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-5

My problem is that there is an Exception being raised in some part of the System, but it happens during initialisation and I can't figure out where or which exception it is. The system just begin to run and then it closes suddenly.

Do you have any methods to debug such a situation?

I am using Delphi5, just in case.

Comment: Do you have Delphi installed on the machine in question?

Comment: Yeah, I run the system with delphi, but I am using Delphi5 I think that it is important.

Comment: Make sure you have selected Debug DCUs. Open <Delphi5InstallDir>\Source\Rtl\Sys\System.pas. Find InitUnits. Set a break point at the beginning. See if you hit it. Step from there until you find the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [MadExcept](http://www.madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm). It works for Delphi 5, is free for non-commercial use (and is a definite bargain for commercial use), and works really well tracking down all sorts of mysterious exceptions.

Comment: Thankyou very much, seems a wonderfull tool. But when I try to recompile my project with madExcept on, it gives this error: 

[Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(10): Unit madTools was compiled with a different version of Windows.GetVersionExW

Did you already seen this?

Comment: You need to make sure you've set your search paths correctly when installing the Mad* files. You're finding the Delphi 2009-Delphi XE versions of the .dcus instead of the Delphi 5 versions. I'm afraid I can't help a lot with Delphi 5; I haven't used it in probably close to a decade now. Did you try the [support forums](http://forum.madshi.net/viewforum.php?f=4) or newsgroups(news://news.madshi.net) that Mathias makes available? (Sorry - can't get the news:// link to work properly.)

Comment: are you building your own vcl by any chance?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Indeed we have our own build of vcl, our company bought the rights to make changes. But there are things that we don't chage like system.pas and some core sources.

Answer (score 2):

Start the application with the <kbd>F7</kbd> (step into) command, this will jump to the first unit initialization... you can then use the <kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>F8</kbd> as usual to debug any unit initialization section until you find the source of your exception.

This is sometimes a tedious work to debug the initialization... while you're making progress, you can put regular breakpoints in initialization sections to start again from a known point.

Comment: I have a problem with this. I am using delphi 5, so I can't debug init sections by F7, because Delphi5 just stops running by consuming 100% CPU.

Comment: @JeanK IIRC this works with any Delphi version, I used this technique since Turbo Pascal old days... maybe you're using a lot of units, in that case to wait some time to let Delphi IDE open the relevant one makes sense to me.

Comment: Yeah, its true, legacy systems are huge. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you get/found where the problem is after using those accepted answer (debugger tool)? Are you using lib/component that require some DLL? As my experience (exception doesn't appear and app closes suddenly); it is because something on your part unable load a DLL. The exception won't show in debug mode, but it'll appear when you just run the app (not in debug-Delphi).